# Rack Error -- LoadError: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Trying to go through the tekpub rack tutorial but run into this error.

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading app.ru

LoadError: cannot load such file -- haiku
```

There is a file named haiku.rb in the same directory as the app I am trying to run but I get the above error while trying to run the program.  Here is the code:

```
class EnvironmentOutput


  def initialize(app=nil)
    @app = app
  end


  def call(env)
    out = ""

    unless(@app.nil?)
 response = @app.call(env)[2]
 out+=response
end

env.keys.each {|key| out+="<li>#{key}=#{env[key]}</li>"}
["200",{"Content-Type" => "text/html"},[out]]
  end
end

require 'haml'
require 'haiku'

class MyApp
  def call(env)

  poem = Haiku.new.random
  template = File.open("views/index.haml").read
  engine = Haml::Engine.new(template)
  out = engine.render(Object.new, :poem => poem)

   ["200",{"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, out]
  end
end

use EnvironmentOutput
run MyApp.new
```

I'm sure its a small error as the code is the same as in the tutorial and it works for him...

Thanks

Comment: If you're running on ruby 1.9, you might want to try `require './haiku.rb'`, or appending the current directory to your load path (`$:.append(File.dirname(__FILE__))`) and then doing `require 'haiku'.

Comment: Thanks that fixes it. Where would I look to try and find that informtaion.  The Rack Documentation or Ruby Docs?

Comment: Reworded my comment as a proper answer just now. It's a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll want to read up on ruby load path (either `$LOAD_PATH` or `$:`). By default, ruby has a load path which includes wherever your gems are installed, which is why you can do `require 'haml'` without providing the full path to where your haml gem is located.

When you type `require 'haiku'`, you're basically telling ruby to look for some file called `haiku.rb` somewhere in it's load path, and the `LoadError` comes from ruby not finding your `haiku.rb` file in any of the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH` (or `$:`, which is just shorthand for `$LOAD_PATH`).

You can solve this in one of (at least) two ways:

1. change `require 'haiku'` to `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/haiku.rb'` to explicitly tell ruby what file to load
2. add the current working directory to your load path: `$:.push(File.dirname(__FILE__))`. This way you can keep the `require 'haiku'` part.

Comment: You might also look into `require_relative` if you're running ruby 1.9.

Comment: I don't think `.append` is a method on the $LOAD_PATH array. Should the code snippet in #2 be `$:.push` or have I got something wrong?

Comment: You are entirely correct. It should either be `$:.push` or `$: <<`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: As a side note on the `$:.push` part, this will append the current directory to the end of the load path. In order to prepend it to the load path, use `unshift` instead of `push`