# Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, require

I've one file, main.rb with the following content:

```
require "tokenizer.rb"
```

The tokenizer.rb file is in the *same directory* and its content is:

```
class Tokenizer
    def self.tokenize(string)
        return string.split(" ")
    end
end
```

If i try to run main.rb I get the following error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\my\src\folder>ruby main.rb

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- tokenizer.rb (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require '
        from main.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I just noticed that if I use `load` instead of `require` everything works fine. What may the problem be here?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative

Comment: Check that the file has `.rb` extension

Answer (score 209, accepted):

I just tried and it works with `require "./tokenizer"`.

Comment: This assumes that the CWD is the directory that the scripts are stored in.

Comment: ...that's why I think it is better to use `require_relative` as I did in my answer.

Comment: still not working for me. even with require_relative. its available tho inside bundle list

Answer (score 204):

Just do this:

```
require_relative 'tokenizer'
```

If you put this in a Ruby file that is in the same directory as `tokenizer.rb`, it will work fine no matter what your current working directory (CWD) is.

### Explanation of why this is the best way

The other answers claim you should use `require './tokenizer'`, but that is the *wrong* answer, because it will only work if you run your Ruby process in the same directory that `tokenizer.rb` is in.  Pretty much the only reason to consider using `require` like that would be if you need to support Ruby 1.8, which doesn't have `require_relative`.

The `require './tokenizer'` answer might work for you today, but it unnecessarily limits the ways in which you can run your Ruby code.  Tomorrow, if you want to move your files to a different directory, or just want to start your Ruby process from a different directory, you'll have to rethink all of those `require` statements.

Using `require` to access files that are on the load path is a fine thing and Ruby gems do it all the time.  But you shouldn't start the argument to `require` with a `.` unless you are doing something very special and know what you are doing.

When you write code that makes assumptions about its environment, you should think carefully about what assumptions to make.  In this case, there are up to three different ways to require the `tokenizer` file, and each makes a different assumption:

1. `require_relative 'path/to/tokenizer'`:  Assumes that the relative path between the two Ruby source files will stay the same.
2. `require 'path/to/tokenizer'`: Assumes that `path/to/tokenizer` is inside one of the directories on the load path (`$LOAD_PATH`).  This generally requires extra setup, since you have to add something to the load path.
3. `require './path/to/tokenizer'`: Assumes that the relative path from the Ruby process's current working directory to `tokenizer.rb` is going to stay the same.

I think that for most people and most situations, the assumptions made in options #1 and #2 are more likely to hold true over time.

Comment: Can you please tell is the meaning of this ? What does it do behind the scenes ? Thanks.

Comment: There's not much to know.  Here's the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) and the [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/eeb05e8c119f8cab6434d90f21551b6bb2954778/load.c#L820-L837) for require_relative.

Comment: This answer is great, not just because of the answer, but because of the crystal clear explanation.

Answer (score 99):

Ruby 1.9 has removed the current directory from the load path, and so you will need to do a relative require on this file, as David Grayson says:

```
require_relative 'tokenizer'
```

There's no need to suffix it with `.rb`, as Ruby's smart enough to know that's what you mean anyway.

Comment: This assumes that the CWD is the directory that the scripts are stored in.

Comment: @RyanBigg - I am new to ruby. Can you please explain what this means - `Ruby 1.9 has removed the current directory from the load path` ? What is this current directory and load path ? Thanks.

Comment: What am I supposed to read in the OP?  Just because the OP happened to have the CWD equal to the directory with the scripts doesn't mean it's always going to be that way, so I like to push for a more robust solution like using `require_relative`.  Tomorrow he might type `cd ..` and then `ruby folder/main.rb` and be sad your solution doesn't work anymore.  I don't think that using `require` has any benefit here.

Comment: Updated for `require_relative` (which didn't exist, or I didn't know about it, at the time of posting)

Comment: yeah... so unless you are using ruby 1.8.7 or earlier ( :O ) there is absolutely no reason not to use require_relative. this is the way to do it

Answer (score 37):

`require` loads a file from the `$LOAD_PATH`. If you want to require a file relative to the currently executing file instead of from the `$LOAD_PATH`, use `require_relative`.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend,

```
load './tokenizer.rb'
```

Given, that you know the file is in the same working directory.

If you're trying to require it relative to the file, you can use

```
require_relative 'tokenizer'
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

Another nice little method is to include the current directory in your load path with

```
$:.unshift('.')
```

You could push it onto the $: ($LOAD_PATH) array but unshift will force it to load your current working directory before the rest of the load path.

Once you've added your current directory in your load path you don't need to keep specifying

```
 require './tokenizer'
```

and can just go back to using

```
require 'tokenizer'
```

Answer (score 9):

This will work nicely if it is in a gem lib directory and this is the tokenizer.rb

```
require_relative 'tokenizer/main'
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are absolutely sure their relative path is correct, my problem was that my files did not have the `.rb` extension! (Even though I used `RubyMine` to create the files and selected that they were `Ruby` files on creation.)

Double check the file extensions on your file!

Answer (score 3):

What about including the current directory in the search path?

```
ruby -I. main.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

I used jruby-1.7.4 to compile my ruby code.

```
require 'roman-numerals.rb'
```

is the code which threw the below error.

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- roman-numerals
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at /Users/amanoharan/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at /Users/amanoharan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/RubyApplication/RubyApplication1/Ruby2.rb:2
```

I removed rb from require and gave

```
require 'roman-numerals'
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `require` does not load from the current directory. This is what I thought, too but then I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7710022/1108032). For example I tried the following code:

```
irb> f = File.new('blabla.rb')
=> #<File:blabla.rb>
irb> f.read
=> "class Tokenizer\n    def self.tokenize(string)\n        return string.split(
\" \")\n    end\nend\n"
irb> require f
LoadError: cannot load such file -- blabla.rb
        from D:/dev/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `req
uire'
        from D:/dev/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `req
uire'
        from (irb):24
        from D:/dev/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

As it can be seen it read the file ok, but I could not require it (the path was not recognized). and here goes code that works:

```
irb f = File.new('D://blabla.rb')
=> #<File:D://blabla.rb>
irb f.read
=> "class Tokenizer\n    def self.tokenize(string)\n        return string.split(
\" \")\n    end\nend\n"
irb> require f
=> true
```

As you can see if you specify the full path the file loads correctly.

Comment: It is a matter of choice. I personally always like to test what I am doing in interactive console. I make quite many mistakes, and I like getting interactive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
$ sudo gem install colored2
```

And,you should input your password

Then :

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```

Appear
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    hostname "gems.ruby-china.org" does not match the server certificate

Then:

```
$  rvm -v
$ rvm get head
```

Last
What language do you want to use?? [ Swift / ObjC ]

> ObjC

Would you like to include a demo application with your library? [ Yes / No ]

> Yes

Which testing frameworks will you use? [ Specta / Kiwi / None ]

> None

Would you like to do view based testing? [ Yes / No ]

> No

What is your class prefix?

> XMG

Running pod install on your new library.

Answer (score -2):

you need to give the path.
Atleast you should give the path from the current directory. It will work for sure.
./filename

Comment: For clarity, I think you should gave repeated part of the code here with the fix.  Down vote is not mine