# Error while calling ruby code using JRuby in Eclipse Aptana Studio 3 Terminal View

Tags: ruby, jruby, aptana

I have a set of ruby code (which is actually a gem that I extracted and the lib folder contains a bunch of .rb (ruby code).  I have Eclipse Aptana Studio 3 plugin setup and have JRuby

> $ jruby -v
>   jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.
>   6.0_45-b06 [Windows 7-amd64]

I need to execute a ruby file:  /lib/my_rubycaller.rb, which is like the following:

```
#dependencies for part0
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'


#dependencies for abcd
require "rexml/document"
require "find"
require "ostruct"
require 'somedependency'

class MyRubyCaller
  def get_somedata(first_param,b,c)
  <some code goes here>
  return test_sr
end

end
```

Now at the Aptana Studio 3 Terminal View, I typed the following:

> $ jruby -S lib/my_rubycaller.rb
>   LoadError: no such file to load -- somedependency
>     require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
>     require at c:/Users/mkorapat/MyProjects/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/cor
>   e_ext/kernel_require.rb:51
>      (root) at my_rubycaller.rb:11

Inside my_rubycaller @ line# 11, I have the require statement.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I am new to Ruby development, but since I am versatile with Eclipse, just stuck to Aptana and JRuby is just because I thought perhaps I could leverage some additional benefits that it has to offer.  But it might still be a matter of time for me to go with Ruby as against JRuby, but still, I wonder how it will help me in this scenario.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

just changed require to require_relative - since apparently my JRuby version seems to use ruby 1.9 and I see that require_relative is the way to go.  Refer to [Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750610/ruby-require-error-cannot-load-such-file).  So long so good. Thanks.