# setting up rails 4 ruby 2.0 on ubuntu 12.02

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Hi I am planing to switch my development machine from windows to ubuntu. But i am hitting this error
i have ruby -v of 2.0.0p0

on  `rails s`

```
/home/rigel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- hitimes/hitimes (LoadError)
    from /home/rigel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/rigel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
```

updating gem -v did not work for me as intended https://github.com/copiousfreetime/hitimes/issues/17
`gem -v 2.4.1
hitimes (1.2.2)`

**Updates**
as suggested by art reinstall gem for me worked

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750610/ruby-require-error-cannot-load-such-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use that at all, but I think it is covered here:

https://github.com/copiousfreetime/hitimes/issues/17

And, according to it, you probably just need to run `gem install hitimes` to get a version that is works with Ruby 2.0.

Comment: or `gem pristine hitimes --version 1.2.2`, which worked for me.