# Require doesn't work

Tags: ruby, require

I wrote a class in an extern file. When I try to import it in my main file, I got an error. This is how I import my file `Money.rb` and `Transaction.rb` :

```
require 'Money'
require 'Transaction'
```

And this sis the error I got :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- Money (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from Krusty.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand why...
Thank you for your help, have a good day !

Comment: Feel like this may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750610/ruby-require-error-cannot-load-such-file

Comment: By convention, filenames in ruby do not use upper-cased letters. They use snake_case instead. JFYI

Comment: @hlcfan Thanks, ```require_relative``` works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev even for a class name?

Comment: For class name "UserRegistration", the filename should be "user_registration.rb"