# El Capitan + Ruby/Brew/major issues

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-elcapitan

I've read a ton about how El Capitan's SIP messes up brew, ruby, and it's gems. The most recent thing I read is that brew was updated to better support El Capitan, so I followed a number of commands from an article online and apparently cleaned my whole system up and reinstalled all gems. Now, from terminal, everything works great. I don't have to write anything special to install gems... just `gem install <name>`.

However, SublimeText seems to be using a different Ruby. If I type which ruby, it shows as /usr/local/bin/ruby. But in SublimeText, it's showing this error about not finding the right gem (mechanize in this case): `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)`

I tried creating a different build system file for Ruby, which points to ruby at /usr/local/bin/ruby, but it still shows this error (but below, it shows `[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/ruby']...`

This has also caused me major issues trying to get the shoes gem to install.

Long question shortened: is there a definitive way to clear my system of all past brew, ruby, gems, etc etc, and redo it in a proper way that actually works for El Capitan?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout @paskal answer here: [Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750610/ruby-require-error-cannot-load-such-file)

Try changing `require <file name>` with  `require "./<File name>".`