# Ruby - NameError: uninitialized constant. Using class from a different module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these 2 files in a large system, both are located in **PackA**

1. people.rb

```
module People
  class HobbyValueObject
  end
end
```

2. job.rb

```
module People
  class Job
  end

  class CityValueObject
  end
end
```

I am trying to use CityValueObject in a different module like this,

Module is in **PackB**

3. work.rb

```
module Profile
   class Work
       ....
       def calculateTaxes
          ...
          a = People::CityValueObject....
       end
   end
end
```

But it's giving me an error saying,

> NameError: uninitialized constant **People::CityValueObject**
>
> Did you mean?  **People::HobbyValueObject**

Why is not being able to fine **CityValueObject** but can find **HobbyValueObject** just fine?
How do I make it find the object that I am intending to use?

I am not explicitly declaring any requires or includes

Comment: Is it possible that the one file was already required and loaded, but the other file was not? Where are the files located, and what are they named? Hint: Rails autoloading only works when files and the classes inside those files follow certain naming conventions.

Comment: I edited the question with those details.
I think you might be right about how autoloading only works with certain naming conventions.

I might have to explicitly import the file I am trying to use.

Comment: Do you really need to define CityValueObject in `job.rb`? The easiest solution is to just move it into its own file. Alternatively you can just "fool" the autoloader by referencing `People::Job` first.

Comment: I do not have the ownership over People module so I can only work within how I can import the class that I need.

Comment: What do you mean by "PackA" and "PackB"? Are those directories or maybe gems? How are these files being loaded? Do you rely on Rails' autoloading or do you load / require them explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding require at the top while using full path file name.

```
require './packs/people/app/public/people/job'
```

Comment: Using `.` in a `require` statement is pretty brittle.  `require_relative` is better.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9750732/28128